# How do I insert a validator using validators.regexp in Python 3.6?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, validation

I have a form. One of the questions is what is your favourite animal. I want any derivation of "dog" to be accepted:

CORRECT:

```
dog
doggie
hounddog
hounddoggie
bigdoggie
```

My class code currently looks like this:

```
dog_check = StringField('Favourite animal:', validators=[validators.required(), validators.regexp(regex='dog')])
```

How do I insert a wildcard? I tried adding | and * like `|dog|` and `*dog*` but that didn't seem to work. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Regular expressions are complex. You may want to read up a bit (you can start [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html), but volumes have been written on the subject) before you try to use them.

Comment: Actually, the python docs are probably not a good place to start... but there are lots of tutorials out there.

Comment: I think you're looking to prepend/append `\S*` as [`\S*dog\S*`](https://regex101.com/r/tMNraX/1)

Comment: It is common knowledge that you may use `.*` to match any 0+ chars, use `.*dog.*`

Comment: ctwheels solution worked. Thanks!